# Automatically disposing Redis connections

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

Something I've noticed with ServiceStack Redis (admittedly far too late) is that it doesn't automatically dispose of it's connections when it's finished with them. If you forget to dispose them using a using statement or call dispose(), it's left for Redis itself to time them out and get rid of them, but this can take a long time and can end up with ridiculous numbers of idle connections.

So what I'm wondering is if there's some way to tell the garbage collection to automatically dispose of the connections just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Redis Clients encapsulates a TCP Connection which does need to be explicitly disposed after you've finished using it. If you're using a [Pooled Redis ClientManager](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-client-managers) this just returns the client back into the Pool (i.e. it doesn't close the TCP connection).

If you access the `base.Redis` property in your ServiceStack Service it's only created when it's used and does get disposed automatically by using a lazy property and disposing it in the Services `Dispose()` method, e.g:

```
public class Service 
{
    private IRedisClient redis;
    public virtual IRedisClient Redis
    {
        get { return redis ?? (redis = RedisManager.GetClient()); }
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        if (redis != null)
            redis.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You can follow a similar pattern in your dependencies, otherwise you should use a using statement to ensure the client is always disposed after use, e.g:

```
using (var redis = redisManager.GetClient())
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is a .Net feature I'm not aware of, but what's a ServiceStack Service? Also, I'm not sure where you're getting RedisManager from.

Comment: It's [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net) `Service` class. You use any  [Redis Client Manager](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-client-managers) to resolve Redis Clients. The RedisManager is just an instance of `IRedisClientsManager`, you can find a complete example in the [LogicBase](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/ILogic.cs#L57) class.

Comment: Is this supposed to be inherited from then? Otherwise Dispose won't be called.

Comment: This is just a normal dependency class, if you use an IOC it gets disposed at the end of the Request. If you're not using an IOC, forget about it and just use it in a using statement and dispose of it explicitly, i.e. how you would dispose of any other resource that needs to be disposed.